# -- Adding a keydown event to a HTMLUListElement

Tags: jquery, events, keydown

I have a unordered list of items. When it prints to the console, it shows up as a "HTMLUListElement". Can I register jquery's keydown event to this element of the page? Right now it's seems? to be working as if I keep that function in there, the page eventually will crash (Chrome says it's unresponsive).

Answer (score 0):

According to w3school's pages for [`<ul>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) and [`<li>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp), the keydown event should work for lists. However, I have no personal experience using this event in lists.